# issues on new phone gap project

Tags: cordova, xcode4

I have started a new cordova project of version 2.9.1 on Xcode4.5.2 .I have created a new project and when we try to run it, getting the following error; i googled it but i can't find any solution, my os version is 10.9.2

- /Users/admin/Desktop/a/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVCapture.m:605:14: Property 'edgesForExtendedLayout' not found on object of type 'CDVAudioRecorderViewController *'
- /Users/admin/Desktop/a/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVCapture.m:605:39: Use of undeclared identifier 'UIRectEdgeNone'

can anyone help me please, aim struggling with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that UIRectEdgeNone is not available in iOS SDK < 7. I found this and works great:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 70000
#define IOS7_SDK_AVAILABLE 1
#endif

#ifdef IOS7_SDK_AVAILABLE
　　if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)]) {
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
    }
#endif
```